# Will Salesforce.com eventually port the Force.com IDE to Eclipse Che?

Tags: ide, force.com-ide, roadmap

When I learned about [the new Eclipse Che](https://www.eclipse.org/che/) I thought it would be a perfect-match for a

- modern browser- and cloud-based IDE for Salesforce.com
- a replacement for the [prototypish Developer console](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iALkAAM)
- easy to port from [existing Force.com IDE code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore)

Are there any plans at Salesforce.com investing in Che?

*Please don't flag this. I know this is somewhat #SafeHarbour but I guess there is a lot of interest in the community about better IDE for Salesforce.*

Comment: Isn't it open source now?

Comment: @AdrianLarson: Sure it is, but Salesforce.com is still driving its development. And I think Salesforce.com is still responsible for proving better to tools to the every growing community. Sure, all the other "alternatives" like Sublime, Cloud9, BrainEngine could also base their products on Che.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess what I was getting at is, we don't necessarily have to wait for SF to do it? I'm sure it is an insane amount of work but they are no longer the only folks with the keys to the kingdom.

Comment: Might want to look into [codenvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codenvy), it looks like theyre working on something close to this, and they have a former salesforce EVP on their Board of Directors. They're also the only active member listed on the [eclipse projects site](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ecd.che).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm the product manager for platform developer tools. We're aware of the Eclipse Che project and we like the technology behind it. Launching a trusted product in our data centers with remote workspaces for 100,000+ simultaneous users is a non trivial engineering effort. We're scoping various options that would meet our goal of providing everyone on platform with an amazing developer experience.

In the meantime we encourage you to use Cloud9 or ASIDE IDE, if you're seeking a similar browser based development experience.

https://get.c9.io/salesforce

https://www.aside.io/login

Comment: We know all the alternatives (client or browser based and still continue working with Eclipse as the other tools just don't feel mature or stable enough. Can't say why but I still hope for a mature solution by Salesforce.com itself. I have seen so many announcements of "alternative" IDE in the last 5 years and 90% of them never made it into mainstream production.